# JOIN query issue :in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have 2 Tables: table1, table2.

table1 has sso_id which contains some names.

table2 has "type" columns having values "ADMIN", "USER", "DBA" etc.

I have created another table: table3.

In table3, I want to insert "name" (sso_id) from table1 and "role" (type) from table2.

I am using the below Query:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (name, role)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.sso_id='abc' AND t2.type='ADMIN';
```

On running the above query I am getting below error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine (see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cbf28d73a306c72c272c44dee84c5675).  You probably have a bad character in the query string.

Comment: Check your SELECT statement for extra comments. You might have something like `SELECT t1.id, t2.id,` and that final comma is throwing it off.